# IntelliJ: Live Template to replace callback function with an es6 array function

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6

I'm migrating an app from plain javascript to ES6/Typescript and I would like to define a Live Template that replaces plain old javascript code like this:

```
responseError: function (rejection) {
          if (rejection.status === 404) {
            return false;
          } else {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
          }
        }
```

with

```
responseError: (rejection) => {
          if (rejection.status === 404) {
            return false;
          } else {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
          }
        }
```

Does anyone have an idea, how I could create a live template to address this?

Many thanks!

Best,
Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live Templates are not supposed to be used for code replacing - only for creating new snippets.
You can use **Convert to arrow function** intention to replace your code with

```
responseError: rejection => {
        if (rejection.status === 404) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
```

Put cursor on *function* keyword, hit `Alt+Enter`, choose **Convert to arrow function**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To easily create an arrow function callback I created a live template and named if `afc` (arrow function callback).
Template text:

```
($ARG$) => {
$SELECTION$
}
```

I then had to mess around with the "Applicable in" settings to get it to show up in my code when I needed it.

When I type out `someArray.forEach()`, place the cursor in the empty parens, and insert the `afc` live template, it winds up looking like:

```
someArray.forEach(() => {
            
})
```